# MSSQL retrieve a value 1 time in a GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, group-by, distinct

I have a table with the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
[ProductNR] [varchar](14) NULL,
[Location] [int] NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NULL
);

 INSERT INTO Products (ProductNR, Location, Date)
 VALUES 
 ('1234' ,1, '2016-01-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('4567' ,1, '2016-03-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('8978' ,1, '2016-04-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('2578' ,1, '2016-05-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('1234' ,2, '2016-06-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('1234' ,3, '2016-07-17 12:30:50.010');

select count (distinct ProductNR)
from Products
```

Result:

```
|Count|
|  4  |
```

But when I use a GROUP BY statement like I do below:

```
select count (distinct ProductNR) AS Count
from Products
group by MONTH(date)
```

Result:

```
|Count|
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   | 
| 1   |
```

That's a total of **6**, but what I would like to retrieve is the ID once across the whole table/GROUP BY statement this means I only want 4 rows returned back where the first registered date for each ID is counted.

Desired result, where ProductNR **1234** is retrived only once:

```
|Count|
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
| 1   |
```

Comment: It gives me the same result

Comment: The second query counts the number of distinct values *in each group*, in other words, `GROUP BY` has a higher precedence than the `DISTINCT` keyword in the `COUNT()`. Can you please explain the business needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you get the minimum date for each ProductNR then you group by month

```
select  count (distinct ProductNR) AS Count
from
(
    select  ProductNR, Date = min(Date)
    from    Products
    group by ProductNR
) d
group by MONTH(Date)
```

Comment: I was wondering, what if I have 2 "count" statements in my select statement, where the second count should just retrieve everything for each month without the need of "min =(date)"
How is that done?

Answer (score 1):

You can add sub select and work only with lines where date = to minimal date for product

```
  select count (distinct ProductNR) AS Count
    from Products as Products
    where date =(select  min(date) 
                   from Products as MinProd 
                  where MinProd.ProductNR =Products.ProductNR 
                 ) 
    group by MONTH(date)
```

this will work only if there will not be same minimal date 
beater will be use identity column and select top 1 in subquery (this return always only one line)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products2](
[PRD_ID] int identity,
[ProductNR] [varchar](14) NULL,
[Location] [int] NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NULL
);

 INSERT INTO Products2 (ProductNR, Location, Date)
 VALUES 
 ('1234' ,1, '2016-01-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('4567' ,1, '2016-03-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('8978' ,1, '2016-04-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('2578' ,1, '2016-05-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('1234' ,2, '2016-06-17 12:30:50.010'),
 ('1234' ,3, '2016-07-17 12:30:50.010');

select count (distinct ProductNR) AS Count
from Products as Products
where date =(select  min(date) 
               from Products as MinProd 
              where MinProd.ProductNR =Products.ProductNR 
             ) 
group by MONTH(date)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are trying to achieve is this

```
select count (distinct ProductNR) AS Count,min(date)
from Products
group by ProductNR
```

Comment: when you have `group by ProductNR`, `count (distinct ProductNR)` will always gives you 1

Comment: @Squirrel and selecting group by ProductNR with min date will give you multiple?